# Where are headers and footers from the latex kernel defined or explained?

Tags: header-footer

I am interested in understanding how header and footer boxes are defined (in TeX, I guess). Where are they defined? I started with `fancyhdr`, which pointed me to [source2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en), in which I found `ltpageno.dtx`. Here, `\thepage` is explained. The boxes in which `\thepage` exist are not explained here. Oh where, oh where could they be?

Unfortunately, trying to read the `fancyhdr` package code, albeit short, is like trying to read Chinese.

```
$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST)/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
```

Comment: In source2e you have `ltpage.dtx` and `ltoutput.dtx` which at least are closely related to typesetting header and footer.

Comment: @TeXnician Aha. No I did not look there. My search terms were "header" and "footer", neither of which appear in `ltpage.dtx`, apparently.

Comment: @JonathanKomar: `latex.ltx` is the great bunch of all kernel macros in one go ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The boxes in which `\thepage` exist are not explained here. Oh where, oh where could they be?

Macros such as `\thepage` can not be tied to boxes, so this part of the question doesn't really have an answer. `\thepage` is globally defined and like all `\the`*countername*  macros in LaTeX, it gives the current print representation of the `page` counter.

What is true is that in most places the current value of the page counter isn't that useful, it tells you (one more than) the page number of the last page shipped out, but that may or may not be the value of the page that the current text ends on.  So it only makes sense to evaluate `\thepage` at points where the page make-up is known, that is inside the "output routine" which is responsible for making up pages out of the top portion of the main vertical list with the text body, any pending floats such as tables and figures, and the head and foot.

The base latex code has very little code related to the page head and foot.

In the output routine itself (`ltoutput.dtx`) the head is added just after the top margin

```
\vskip \topmargin
\moveright\@themargin \vbox {%
  \setbox\@tempboxa \vbox to\headheight{%
    \vfil
    \color@hbox
      \normalcolor
      \hb@xt@\textwidth{\@thehead}%
    \color@endbox
    }%
```

which basically, after some font and colour normalisation so the page head does not pick up the fonts at at a page break,  is just `\hbox to \textwidth{\@thehead}`

So the important question is: What is in the macro `\@thehead`? That is also set in `ltoutput.dtx` as

```
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\count\z@ \let\@thehead\@oddhead \let\@thefoot\@oddfoot
         \let\@themargin\oddsidemargin
    \else \let\@thehead\@evenhead
       \let\@thefoot\@evenfoot \let\@themargin\evensidemargin
    \fi
  \fi
```

so it is `\@oddhead` or `\@evenhead` depending. These macros are set by the page style. A command `\pagestyle{foo}` executes `\ps@foo`.  LaTeX itself has no specific commands to help define a page style, which is where `fancyhdr` comes in.  But without `fancyhdr` latex format defines (in `ltpage.dtx`) `empty` and `plain` styles, the latter is

```
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage
     \hfil}\let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
```

so in `plain` page style the page head is empty, and the page foot has a centred page number.